# Make inserted image fit content div in blogdown

Tags: r-markdown, knitr, blogdown

In [this blog post](http://djnavarro.net/post/2018-04-27-starting-blogdown/) the author is using images that are larger a larger size than is displayed. When I use the RStudio addin to put a large image, on the other hand, it is inserted as-is and overflows the text box.

Apart from the addin, I have tried using `knitr::include_graphics`, but the result is the same.

Example:

[image: example]

The above post was created with this code:

````
---
title: image test
author: ''
date: '2019-01-17'
slug: image-test
categories: []
tags: []
---

Image below overflows text width text width text width text width text width text width text width text width text width text width text width text width text width text width text width text width text width text width text width text width text width text width text width text width text width text width text width text width text width text width text width text width text width text width text width text width text width text width text width text width text width text width text width text width text width text width text width text width text width text width text width text width text width text width text width text width.

![](https://forestry.io/uploads/2018/01/hugo-vs-jekyll-advanced2.png)

```{r, echo = FALSE}
knitr::include_graphics("https://forestry.io/uploads/2018/01/hugo-vs-jekyll-advanced2.png")
```
````

(only one of the images is shown in the picture but both methods produce the same outcome)

Comment: Please post sample code that illustrates the issue.  It doesn't need to be your real image and document, just a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @user2554330 added the example with the two methods I know of

Comment: Okay, using `![](img){width=100%}` fixes the issue.